# Where can I see the list of my saved drafts?

Tags: support, draft

I am not able to find the "my drafts" section on a Stack Exchange site.

Where is it?

Comment: TL;DR: no such list or section. Request asking for it is pending, see dupe.

Comment: @ShadowWizard reading [the OP's recent post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308034/drafts-invisible-in-android), it seems the OP was confused because (IIRC) the SO app has a multi-draft feature. But yeah, there's no such feature on the website.

Comment: You go to the left side on top, and you must see the 3 lines and after this, click on the 3 lines and then you need to scroll up or down and then you’ll see the word “drafts” and when you click on it, you’ll see your saved drafts.

Comment: @Dreadbot can you post a screenshot? I do not see it!

Comment: @Djeah When you see the word “Feed” then look to the left side, click on it and then you’ll see the word “drafts” I can’t make a picture because your post is closed.

Comment: @Dreadbot I added the screenshot to my question. It is not available for me it seems!

Comment: @Djeah Well that’s because you have to choose a site first and then you’ll see the word “Feed” and then look at the left side and then click the three lines and then you’ll see the word “drafts”.

Comment: @Dreadbot please don't confuse people here. You talk about **iOS app**, this question is about the site, as viewed in a browser. Obviously, OP here has no idea such app even exists, so better not confuse him any further. I rolled back totally irrelevant edit, adding screenshots showing the site has no drafts list.